# gob: type not registered for interface: http.gzipReader

Tags: go, gob

I a simple TCP server that accept connection , Get a URL using http.Get and then encode the response using gob. But gob fails to encode http.gzipReader.
On encoding it gives following error message:

```
gob: type not registered for interface: http.gzipReader
```

My code is given below:

```
package main
import (
    "encoding/gob"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)
const (
    CONN_HOST = "localhost"
    CONN_PORT = "3333"
    CONN_TYPE = "tcp"
)

func main() {
    // Listen for incoming connections.
    l, err := net.Listen(CONN_TYPE, CONN_HOST+":"+CONN_PORT)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error listening:", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    for {
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error accepting: ", err.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        go handleRequest(conn)
    }
}
func handleRequest(conn net.Conn) {
    res, err :=
        http.Get("http://info.cern.ch/hypertext/WWW/TheProject.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        encoder := gob.NewEncoder(conn)
        er := encoder.Encode(res)
        if er != nil {
            fmt.Println(er)
        }
    }
    conn.Write([]byte("Message received."))
    conn.Close()
}
```

Is there any way to encode  http.gzipReaderc ?? I saw an example of gob.Register() , but I am trying to registrer http.gzipReaderc . But unable to do so. can any one suggest me solution to this problem ?

Comment: I got this error: `gob: type not registered for interface: http.bodyEOFSignal`. Are sure that you want to encode the whole part of [`http.Response`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response)?  The content (HTML page) of `http.Get` response is available through `Body` field (which is an interface and the data itself may not yet available immediately or it may be encoded in gzip etc.) and you should read it first into a buffer (or create a wrapper) then passing it to the gob encoder.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by implementing my own `ReadCloser`. Check [HTTP Caching Client](https://github.com/meehow/http-caching-client/blob/master/client.go#L21)